# Underscore debounce for 2 - 3 seconds

Tags: underscore.js

I'm using underscore and this `_.debounce` function and tried `_.debounce(foo(),350)` and it works perfect. But when I try to `_.debounce(foo(),3000)` it executes immediately. any ideas?

the actual code:

```
 $('input').on('input',function(){
     _.debounce(validate(),3000)
 });
```

Comment: Code works as intended, you're not accidentally passing `true` after your milliseconds, are you?

Comment: I don't. I'll post the exact code

Comment: You are calling validate when the debounce is called. Try something like var debouncedValidate = _.debounce(validate, 3000); $('input').on( 'input, debouncedValidate);

Comment: @GruffBunny That works but how to do it when there are parameters for the function()?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @GruffBunny

So here how it works,

Place the function to be called in a variable and make sure it's outside the event loop

```
function validate(data,field){
  Your code goes here...
}

var validateNow =_.debounce(validate,3000) // Make sure there's no open and close          parentheses

 $('input').on('input',function(){
     validateNow('foodata','field')
 });
```

and voila it works :D.